# What are some techniques companies like Linode use to prevent spamming from their VPS's?

Tags: linode

I apologize if this seems open ended.

I'm currently investigating Linode, and this item is one of the things I was asked to look into.  I suspect this may look like I'm a spammer myself, but that's not the case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably contract Linode to get their "latest" policy. The same goes with most hosting providers, who are usually pretty open about their policy and how they enforce it.

Last I knew, Linode's policy was something to the effect of they don't monitor what you're doing unless/until someone complains. Most of the major mail providers (Google, Outlook, AOL, Yahoo, etc) will automatically report you to Linode if you're sending spam. A human will get involved, if it really looks like spam, you're getting suspended - if not, they'll contact you, and you'll have to "make adjustments" to what you're sending.

Footnote plea from every mail server admin in the world: If you don't know how to run a mail server, stay the **** out of the kitchen. Mail servers aren't that hard, but people muck them up on a constant basis, and the rest of the world has to deal the the BS and spam they spew. Thanks!!

Comment: lol, fair enough :)